# lightning-output-field not displaying anything

Tags: lightning-web-components

HTML:

```
    <template if:true={showDates}>
        <lightning-record-view-form
                record-id="recordId"
                object-api-name="CC_Case__c">
            <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Case_Name__c">
                </lightning-output-field>
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Country__c">
                </lightning-output-field>
            </div>
        </lightning-record-view-form>
    </template>
. . .
```

js:

```
export default class AddDays extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track showDates = true;
. . .
```

recordId is the correct sobject id.

I get a blank box when displaying lwc:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an error in your HTML code. Change the HTML code to as below and it will work

```
<template if:true={showDates}>
    <lightning-record-view-form
            record-id={recordId}
            object-api-name="CC_Case__c">
        <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
            <lightning-output-field field-name="Case_Name__c">
            </lightning-output-field>
            <lightning-output-field field-name="Country__c">
            </lightning-output-field>
        </div>
    </lightning-record-view-form>
</template>
. . .
```

You are refering record-id as a string instead of it being an expression which means you shouldn't use "" and use {} instead. Please read more about this [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_attributes)

Comment: Ugh. Thanks,That did it.